# IdentityServer4 authenticate each client separately

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, identityserver4, asp-net-core-spa-services

I use two different clients. The IdentityServer4 provides API protections and log in form. Can I configure clients to avoid single sign on. I mean that even if I logged in the first client I need to log in the second client too.

My ID4 configuration:

```
internal static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(IEnumerable<RegisteredClient> clients)
{
    return clients.Select(x =>
    {
        var scopes = x.AllowedScopes.ToList();
        scopes.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
        scopes.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile);
        scopes.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess);

        var client = new Client
        {
            ClientId = x.Id,
            ClientName = x.Name,
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,

            RequireConsent = false,

            RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
            RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,

            ClientSecrets = {new Secret(x.Secret.Sha256())},
            RedirectUris = new[] {$"{x.Url}/signin-oidc"},
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = new[] {$"{x.Url}/signout-callback-oidc"},

            UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,

            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            AllowedScopes = scopes,
            AllowedCorsOrigins = {x.Url},
            AllowOfflineAccess = true
        };

        return client;
    });
}
```

All client have the same register code (Maybe it is a problem):

```
const string oidcScheme = "oidc";
const string coockieScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = coockieScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = oidcScheme;
})
    .AddCookie(coockieScheme)
    .AddOpenIdConnect(oidcScheme, options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = coockieScheme;

        options.Authority = identitySettings.Authority;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ClientId = identitySettings.Id;
        options.ClientSecret = identitySettings.Secret;

        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        foreach (var scope in identitySettings.Scopes)
        {
            options.Scope.Add(scope);
        }

        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    });
```

any help will be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you are in the same browser session, and your apps are having the same authority (are using the same Identity Server) this will not work.

I'll explain you why - once you log in from the first client, Identity Server creates a cookie (with all the relevant data needed in it).

Now comes the second client - the authority (the Identity Server) is the same that has issued the cookie. So Identity Server recognizes your session, sees that you are already authenticated and redirects you to the second client, without asking for credentials.

After all, this is the idea of Identity Server:

> IdentityServer4 is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET Core 2.
>
> It enables the following features in your applications:
>
> **Authentication as a Service**
>
> Centralized login logic and workflow for all of your applications (web, native, mobile, services). IdentityServer is an officially certified implementation of OpenID Connect.
>
> **Single Sign-on / Sign-out**
>
> Single sign-on (and out) over multiple application types.
>
> and more....

This is from the [official documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/).

You have to either go for different authorities (Identity Server instances) for each client, or re-think is Identity Server the right solution for you in this case.

**NOT RECOMMENDED**

I'm not recommending this, because it kind of overrides the SSO idea of Identity Server, however if you still want to do it then - you can achieve what you want if you override the `IProfileService`. There is a method `public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)` and this context has a property `IsActive` which determines if the current principal is active in the current client.

You can try and implement some custom logic here, and based on the user ID (`context.Subject.GetSubjectId()`) and the client id (`context.Client.ClientId`) to determine if the user is already logged in this client or not.

**EDIT**

After your comment - this is something that doesn't come OOTB from Identity Server (if I can say it like this), but luckily you have an option.

[Policy based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1) per client. Like this, your user can *authenticate* against Identity Server (and all of its clients), but only the specific clients will *authorize* him. You can treat this policies as a custom authorize attribute (more or less).

Like this, a user will receive unauthorized in clients, where he.. is not authorized. Hope that this clears the thing and helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what if I need to implement several internal/public apps and to ensure just specific users can access specific clients? It seems the ordinary case, I think ID4 should provide a build-in mechanism to implement this.

Comment: After a reading the IS documentation and a github discussing I understand the SSO approach completely, I hope. In my case I can use Roles with my client apps, so we separate authentication (IS SSO) and authorization (Roles).

Comment: Exactly. This is the proper way of doing the things. IS's job is to *authenticate*, and the client's job is to *authorize* and this things should remain separated.

Comment: I see your point but I could argue that authenticating a user should take under consideration the client the user is coming from. I think there is something missing from IDSRV4. There should be a setting to disable this SSO behavior if we do not want it or to be able to associate Users to Clients/Tenants. Thanks for the answer though. It was very helpful to me as well!

Comment: @Apollonas did you find any mentioned nuances about SSO behavior?

Comment: @DaniilDoronkin how did you solve the issue, could you provide the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `prompt=login` from all your clients.

```
prompt
none - no UI will be shown during the request. If this is not possible (e.g. because the user has to sign in or consent) an error is returned

login - the login UI will be shown, even if the user is already signed-in and has a valid session
```

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html

This will force the second client to login again regardless of the previous client's login status.