# Control users allowed to login to clients with SSO identityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, multi-tenant, identityserver4

IdentityServer4 provides SSO experience along with the STS functionalities. SSO works As soon as the clients are validated as per the OAuth OpenId Connect. So the users if the identity is based on the cookie.

I was wondering if any one implemented this for multitenancy fashion to restrict users to allow only set of clients (means SSO still works among them - let's call the group as a tenant). When it comes to non-allowed users and clients, the identity server should take them to a login screen.

Configuration on the startup - AspNetIdentity for users store

```
     services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager>()
                .AddSignInManager<CustomSignInManager>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            //TODO Tenant based cookie SaasKit/Finbuckle
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(cookieOptions =>
            {
                cookieOptions.Cookie = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieBuilder
                {
                    Name="Tenant_Cookie"
                };
            });   

 var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                }).AddSigningCredential(GetSigningCertificate("my", "a7 e2 f5 f7 9a b8 8c 86 2c 37 f5 22 1b ea 8c 19 b1 58 99 3c", true))                  
                .AddResponseGenerators()
                .AddCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator<TenantAuthorizeRequestValidator>()
                .AddCustomTokenRequestValidator<TenantTokenRequestValidator>()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

Tenant Token request validator - Validate user and client

```
 public class TenantTokenRequestValidator : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
    HttpContext _context;
    IClientService _clientService;
    public TenantTokenRequestValidator(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IClientService clientService)
    {
        _context = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
        _clientService = clientService;
    }

    public Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Result.IsError)
        {
            //AuthorizationCode authorization_code
            if (context.Result.ValidatedRequest.UserName!=null && 
                !_clientService.IsValidUser(context.Result.ValidatedRequest.Client.ClientId,context.Result.ValidatedRequest.UserName))
            {
                context.Result.IsError = true;
                context.Result.Error = "UnauthorizedUser";
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Tenant authorize request validator - Validate Client and tenant

```
 public class TenantAuthorizeRequestValidator : ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
{
    HttpContext _context;
    ITenantService _tenantService;
    public TenantAuthorizeRequestValidator(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,ITenantService tenantService)
    {
        _context = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
        _tenantService = tenantService;
    }
    public Task ValidateAsync(CustomAuthorizeRequestValidationContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Result.IsError)
        {
            var tenant = context.Result.ValidatedRequest.GetTenant();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenant))
            {                  
                if (!_tenantService.IsValidClient(tenant,context.Result.ValidatedRequest.ClientId))
                {
                    context.Result.IsError = true;
                    context.Result.Error = OidcConstants.AuthorizeErrors.UnauthorizedClient;
                }
                context.Result.ValidatedRequest.ClientClaims.Add(new Claim(
                TenantConstants.TokenKey,
                tenant,
                IdentityServerConstants.ClaimValueTypes.Json));
            }             


            //Find a way to respond the error message
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Database is like

```
public static Dictionary<string, string[]> TenantClients()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
        {
            { "tenant1",new string[]{ "tenant1.mvc","tenant1.mvc2" } },
            { "tenant2",new string[]{ "tenant2.mvc" } }
        };
    }
public static Dictionary<string, string[]> ClientUsers()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
        {
            { "tenant1.mvc", new string[]{"alice","bob"} },
            { "tenant1.mvc2", new string[]{"alice","bob"} },
            { "tenant2.mvc", new string[]{"alice"}}
        };
    }
```

I'm validating the client and tenant also client and user with the above. However not been able to achieve tenant based cookie so that different logins will work on the same browser session with different cookies. Saaskit doesnot seem to work well with aspnet core 2.0, Not finding a way with finbuckle.

question - How to set the cookie name with tenant? resolving from the request based on the context acr values. does this approach works?

Comment: I think you are mixing authentication and authorization policy.   Its not your identity servers job to define who has access to what that the policy servers job.

Comment: I agree with DalmTo. Check my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49880489/identityserver4-authenticate-each-client-separately/49884452#49884452 . Basically you are mixing the `authorization` and the `authentication`, which you should not do

Comment: My situation was similar, but with a different ID provider. We use our IDP to Authenticate and pass back to a Login page on our website. From there, the site will look up the user in OUR database to see if they are Authorized to access the site. If so, we give them a cookie and set up Claims, etc. Is this something you're interested in, or are you hoping to keep Authorization outside your site?

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3  it make sense to separate authentication and authorization when it comes to roles as user role may be different in each client. our IDM implementation is trying to reduce the amount of work on the client app, so we can use this across our apps with a configuration. we can easily handle at the client side checking the claim policy on authorize which takescare of user and client validation.But acr_values tenant purpose is a bit confusing!!

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks it make sense to separate both (as the framework designers are also recommend this). But claim based policy on the client will be the simplest way to manage this.

Comment: @AndrewS I see the check is on the login post to see the logging use is authorized to the client in the request. Some what I'm trying to implement the same which is why I needed to tenant based cookie. Tenant is a group of clients (who wants SSO), Each user mapped to client/Clients. If two clients from different tenant group have access to same user, then they have to login twice, because the cookie is different to each successful login.

Comment: I guess our options are to use .net core 2.1 (support custom IOptions/Ioptionssnapshot/IOptionsMonitor implementation where context will be available to give a cookie name). or Finbuckle/Sasskit which does similar. ... another option, leaving the authorization to the client app.

Comment: I have the same need. Yet I do think the solution is at cookie generation logic (where you would set the cookie to "belong to certain tenant and domain"). I am still researching for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have end up adding an extra bunch of client specific claims to the user accounts and set the authorization policy based on the incoming claims.

For instance-

Api resource wants to restrict the access based on the scope in the token, which is fine for client validation, and for user validation looks for a specific claim in the token and gives access.

With the above approach we had to maintain the claims for users coming through UI, for other clients accessing server to server without user, into the client claims.

Though its not the best approach, this solved our current requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The way we have done it is that you need to create several AddCookie in the startup one for each tenant with its own scheme name.

Then in the ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator you set the scheme name to be the same as the scheme you created for the tenant (so probably you have to define a common format like: Cookies-MyTenantId1, or Cookies-MyTenantId2). This way a different cookie gets created for each tenant.